# How to determine if all the option tags has a same attribute value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select tag containing my options:

```
    <select name="series" onchange="changeCalc()" id="idCalcSelect" class="CalcSelect">
<option selected="1" style="display:none;">Series</option>
<option style="display:none;">Parallel</option>
<option style="display:none;">Semi</option>
</select>
```

I need a jquery code that can give me true if all the options have style="display: none;".

So far, I need something

```
jq("#idCalcSelect").on("mouseover", function(){
    jq("select[name='series'] > option[style]").each(function () {
        /*jquery code here!*/                                                   
    });                                                 
});
```

If there is a single option tag that doesn't match the style="display: none;", the jquery code must return false.

Comment: just use if else

Comment: @Kasnady, I need to check every option tags that is under my select tag. That's like a sample, but there are so many options that i have in that particular select tag so I cannot use if else.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can compare the number of options with the number of [hidden](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) options.

```
jq("#idCalcSelect").on("mouseover", function(){
    var options = jq(this).find('option');
    // check if all options are hidden
    if (options.length === options.filter(":hidden").length) {
       // if so, do whatever                                                   
    }                                             
});
```